# VBA user form fill in entire column

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Hello I am writing a user form code in VBA.

The code finds the column with the given name and then it should fill in the column until the last row, which contains data, with the value from the user form.

Any ideas how can I do this?

```
Dim intBB As Integer
Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, intBB) <> ""
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, intBB).Value = "HPL" Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                Set rngBB = .Range(.Cells(1, intBB), .Cells(1, intBB))                    
             End With
         Exit Do

        End If
          intBB = intBB + 1
    Loop

Cells(2, intBB).Value = HPLBox.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find the last used row in the column you find with :
`LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intBB).End(xlUp).Row`

And then you can apply the value to the whole range directly : `rngBB.value = HPLBox.value`

```
Dim intBB As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rngBB As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Do While .Cells(1, intBB) <> vbNullString
        If .Cells(1, intBB).value <> "HPL" Then
        Else
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intBB).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rngBB = .Range(.Cells(1, intBB), _
                                .Cells(LastRow, intBB))
            Exit Do
        End If
        intBB = intBB + 1
    Loop
End With
rngBB.value = HPLBox.value
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go like follows

```
Dim rngBB As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngBB = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Find(what:="HPL", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not rngBB Is Nothing Then  .Range(rngBB.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.count, rngBB.Column).End(xlUp)).Value = HPLBox.Value
End With
```